# Выбор ошибок 404, 500

Tags: django

Есть кусок кода:

```
if request.META['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '192.168.0.0':
        return HttpResponse("SUCCESS")
else:
    return render(request, "alert/success.html", {'s':s})
```

Какую ошибку отдавать, если под условие не подходит 404, 500 и т.д.?

Comment: @avdoshkin, насколько понял Вы проверяете IP клиента (лучше бы сами **русскими словами** описали смысл кусочка кода).

Если не подходит, я бы вернул **403 - Forbidden**

Answer (score 3):

Как я понимаю из приведённого кода идёт проверка на доступность для поределённого IP. Следовательно для тех, кому доступа нет, логично отдавать 403 ошибку…

В случае разрешения отдаётся 200 код, вместе с контентом.

Answer (score 0):

**[Вот список](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_HTTP)** всех возможных кодов состояния протокола HTTP... Далее карты Вам в руки.

Comment: Первым делом прочитал)